# How to write single loop for a matrix using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop

Why can't i use the code below?
I know that a matrix is defined like a one dimentional array follow by each other.

How can i make it possible?

**All I need is optimization.**

```
MyStructure* myStructure[8][8];
int i = 0;

for(MyStructure* s = myStructure[0][0]; i<64; i++,s++)
{

}
```

Comment: Never use `Type* variable`. Always use `Type *variable`. Mind the space. The * is part of the variable, not the type. Consider, `int *foo, goo` vs. `int* foo, goo`.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Because this much code seems to work. I think we need more context here.

Comment: @user3427419: Not quite. And plenty of places prefer the `Type* variable` syntax

Comment: `s` is not an address of `myStructure[0][0]` (which would be of type `MyStructure**`) - it's the value of `myStructure[0][0]`. `s++` moves to the next element in the array to which `myStructure[0][0]` points (and if it doesn't point to an array, then your program exhibits undefined behavior). In any case, the value of `s++` bears no relation to `myStructure[0][1]` nor `myStructure[1][0]`

Comment: @user3427419 What of type * foo?

Comment: `type * foo` is also unreadable. The reason for `Type *foo` is that the type of Type, not Type*. What is written by original author is clearly Java syntax. Also, multidimensional arrays are frowned upon. As for the error, replace your MyStructure* with int and you'll see it better.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik s is an pointer. we have a matrix of pointers.

Comment: Right, but pointers to the wrong thing. You have a pointer to a single element in the array. That pointer is getting incremented not the pointer to the pointer's location in the array. I'm going to post an answer now and post the explanation with  an edit. Look at what happens with the output.

Comment: Not all pointers are created equal. If you have an array of `int`, you can iterate over it using `int*` pointer. Similarly, if you have an array of `int*`, you iterate over it using `int**` pointer; for an array of `int**`, you need `int***`, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is tougher to demonstrate this with pointers to objects, I've subbed in the common integer in place of the pointer to MyStructure. The levels of indirection are unchanged, and it is the level of indirection that matters to the OP's problem.

By the way, do not do this. Use Ediac's solution. I'm only trying to point out where things went wrong for the OP. Walking through a 2D array in one dimension ***MAY*** work. And it may not. Have fun debugging that! This is only working because it's easy to implement a 2D array as a 1D array, but to my knowledge this behaviour is not guaranteed. It is certainly not guaranteed with a vector or other conventional dynamic array solution. Please slap me down if I'm wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//begin function @ Seraph: Agreed. Lol.
int main()
{
    // ordering the array backwards to make the problem stand out better.
    // also made the array smaller for an easier demo
    int myStructure[4][4] = {{16,15,14,13},{12,11,10,9},{8,7,6,5}, {4,3,2,1}};
    int i = 0;

    // here we take the contents of the first element of the array
    for (int s = myStructure[0][0]; i < 16; i++, s++)
    {  //watch what happens as we increment it.
        cout << s << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    // output: 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
    // this didn't iterate through anything. It incremented a copy of the first value

    // reset and try again
    i = 0;
    // this time we take an extra level of indirection 
    for (int * s = &myStructure[0][0]; i < 16; i++, s++)
    {
        // and output the value pointed at
        cout << *s << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    // output: 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
    // now we have the desired behaviour.
} //end function end Lol
```

output:

```
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: The original declaration is `MyStructure * myStructure[][]`, not `int myStructure[][]`. And those *"begin/end function"* comments are hilarious.

Comment: @Saraph Trying to make a point. OP needs an extra level of indirection to make the walk he's trying for. And even then he has to count on the rows/columns being contiguous in memory, something I do not believe is guaranteed.

Comment: @Saraph Holy smurph. Didn't know those begin/ends were still there! I cut and pasted the main from another ball of code I was playing with.

Comment: Well, if curly brackets somehow don't manage to hold the awesomeness, pascal will save the day!

Comment: No, [the world will be saved by steam!](http://files1.comics.org//img/gcd/covers_by_id/240/w200/240323.jpg?823001931656483903)

Answer (score 1):

If one loop is all you want, you could do it this way:

```
MyStructure* myStructure[8][8];

for(int i = 0; i<64; i++)
{
    MyStructure* s = myStructure[i/8][i%8];
}
```

You will iterate through every element of the matrix. However, time complexity is still O(rows*columns).

Comment: @EdS. yes, that's why i see no point in not using nested loops :)

Comment: And a hell of a lot safer.

Comment: With 8 the compiler has a lot of lee-way for masking and bitshifting, but I wonder what the performance is like in the general case with the / and % in there vs an extra add and branch on condition for the nested loop.